# ntheorem with thmmarks and standard options fails when thebibliography is empty

Tags: ntheorem

When using an empty `thebibliography` environment, LaTeX normally warns, but goes on typesetting the document. However, it considers the following example as an error: “! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.”

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[thmmarks, standard]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{0}
\end{thebibliography}

\begin{theorem}
    Blah.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Why is this? I didn’t find anything related in the `ntheorem` manual. How can I avoid this behavior, so that an empty `thebibliography` environment produces no error? I am fine with the warning, I just want to avoid compilation failing with an error.

(I am aware that I can ask LaTeX to ignore all errors and try to continue compiling anyway, but I’d prefer not using this option – I want my compilation to fail and stop if there is an error in my document, but I would like an empty `thebibliography` environment followed by a theorem not to produce an error.)

Comment: Silly guess.  It's rather unusual for a bibliography to appear before a theorem.  It might be worth swapping them to see if that changes anything.  You might also try creating a dummy `.bbl` file containing only `\relax`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The compilation error appears only if things are in the order shown. Indeed unusual (I guess that’s the reason this problem has not been solved yet); this situation happens in my case because the bibliography is followed by an appendix, which contains lots of stuff, among which theorems or similar environments which trigger the problem. (I stripped down the example to make it minimal, hence even less realistic.) A `.bbl` file containing `\relax` makes no difference.

Comment: I'm not an `ntheorem` adept; my background is totally `amsthm`.  (And this makes me wonder whether `amsthm` might have a similar problem; it really *is* unusual for a bibliography to appear before a theorem.)  Please try one more experiment -- a `.bbl` file with one dummy entry.  (I'll try this with `amsthm` and alert the responsible folks if there's a problem.)  Then add this additional information to your question so that someone more familiar with `ntheorem` can address with good information.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I thought using `ntheorem` was recommended, reading [amsmath](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath): “several contributed packages add still further to its appeal; examples are empheq, which provides functions for decorating and highlighting mathematics, and ntheorem, for specifying theorem (and similar) definitions” I understand now that this is probably an old recommendation that never got updated. Should I report this somewhere so that other users are not mislead as I have been? (I tend to take AMS recommendations seriously.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I ask LaTeX to show the definition of `\endtrivlist` with `ntheorem` active, I get

```latex
> \endtrivlist=macro:
->\@endtrivlist {\PotEndMark {\unskip \nobreak \hfill \nobreak }}.
l.11 \show\endtrivlist

?
> \@endtrivlist=macro:
#1->\if@inlabel \indent \fi \if@newlist \@noitemerr \fi \ifhmode \ifdim \lastsk
ip >\z@ #1\unskip \par \else \unskip \par \fi \fi \if@noparlist \else \ifdim \l
astskip >\z@ \@tempskipa \lastskip \vskip -\lastskip \advance \@tempskipa \pars
kip \advance \@tempskipa -\@outerparskip \vskip \@tempskipa \fi \@endparenv \fi
 .
l.12 \show\@endtrivlist
```

The original definition of `\endtrivlist` is

```latex
> \endtrivlist=macro:
->\if@inlabel \leavevmode \global \@inlabelfalse \fi \if@newlist \@noitemerr \g
lobal \@newlistfalse \fi \ifhmode \unskip \par \else \@inmatherr {\end {\@curre
nvir }}\fi \if@noparlist \else \ifdim \lastskip >\z@ \@tempskipa \lastskip \vsk
ip -\lastskip \advance \@tempskipa \parskip \advance \@tempskipa -\@outerparski
p \vskip \@tempskipa \fi \@endparenv \fi .
l.11 \show\endtrivlist
```

One can see that the definition make by `ntheorem` misses a few things from the current definition of `\endtrivlist` and so one gets in a very unstable state.

In particular, the redefinition misses the crucial

```
\global \@newlistfalse \fi
```

and this is why you get the `\@noitemerr` when executing `\begin{theorem}`.

I *guess* that the definition of `\endtrivlist` has changed over time, but it's been the same from at least 2006, the first time it entered TeX Live, see http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?revision=694&view=markup

Another reason for not using `ntheorem`.

Comment: “Another reason for not using ntheorem”, could you state what the other reasons are? I thought using it was recommended, reading [amsmath](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath): “several contributed packages add still further to its appeal; examples are empheq, which provides functions for decorating and highlighting mathematics, and ntheorem, for specifying theorem (and similar) definitions”, and [cleveref](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf): “ntheorem is fully supported and even recommended”.

Comment: If one wants to use facilities for theorem-like environments, would you recommend sticking to `amsthm`, or using something else? (In my understanding `ntheorem` supposedly improved over `amsthm`.)

Comment: @OlivierCailloux I only use `amsthm`; unfortunately, `ntheorem` seems essentially unmaintaned and has severe problems.